# call const overloaded function with std::map of std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, shared-ptr

I am trying to call a const overload function

```
void process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>);
```

with data I generate. Because I generate the data, I use a non-const version

```
std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>> my_data;
```

When I try to call my function with

```
process(my_data);
```

I get the error:

```
error C2664: 'void process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
```

I have tried a variety of casting variations but all fail to do the job. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my test code with the casting variants and associated error codes (I am using Visual C++ community edition 2013):

```
struct Data_Struct
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

void process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>);

void calling_function() {
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>> my_data;
    my_data.emplace("test",std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>(new Data_Struct)).first->second->a = 2;
    process(my_data);
        // error C2664: 'void process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
    process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>(my_data));
        // error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
    process((std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>)my_data);
        // error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
    process(static_cast<std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>>(my_data));
        // error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
    process(reinterpret_cast<std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>>(my_data));
        // error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
    process(const_cast<std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>>(my_data));
        // error C2440: 'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
    process(std::static_pointer_cast<std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>>(my_data));
        // error C2784: 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> std::static_pointer_cast(const std::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &) throw()' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &' from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
    process(std::const_pointer_cast<std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>>(my_data));
        // error C2784: 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> std::const_pointer_cast(const std::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &) throw()' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::shared_ptr<_Ty2> &' from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
}

void process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>> data) {
    for(auto &d : data)
        std::cout << d.first << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `process()` takes its parameter by value. This means that when it's called a copy of the map is taken, processed and then discarded. I don't know if that's your intention. Assuming it is, what you need is a conversion function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>


struct Data_Struct
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

void process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>);

std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>>
convert_map(const std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>>& source)
{
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>> ret;
    for(const auto& item : source) {
        ret.emplace(item.first, item.second);
    }
    return ret;
}

void process(std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<const Data_Struct>> data) {
    for(auto &d : data)
        std::cout << d.first << std::endl;
}

void calling_function() {
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>> my_data;
    my_data.emplace("test",std::shared_ptr<Data_Struct>(new Data_Struct)).first->second->a = 2;
    process(convert_map(my_data));
}


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    calling_function();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did not realize that I was passing by value in my test case, I am passing by reference in my use case. However, making a const copy of my map should not incur that much overhead as I am not copying the actual data but only the pointer to the data and a string key. It is not as ideal or beautiful but I was able to get it working in my actual code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The two map types are totally unrelated and in spite of the apparent similiarity cannot be used interchangeably. You do have a few options though:

- Populate your data class in its constructor so you don't have to mutate it after creation.
- Have the process function work on a templated iterator range rather than a specific container.
- Have the process function work on a templated container rather than a specific type.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to populate my data at creation. I want to send the map container as a whole (just a const version) so I don't want to use an iterator. If I used a templated function could I ensure the const-ness of my shared_ptr?